# How to use CultureInfo to format deprecated currencies?

Tags: c#, format, currency, cultureinfo

In dotnet, the recommended way of formatting currencies in a culture-specific way, is (as far as I can find):

```
using System.Globalization
var info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")
return string.Format(info, "{0:c}", 1234.5678)
```

This returns:

```
 £1,234.57
```

However. No specific currency is given here. So if Great Britain ever converts to Euro, the same method would suddenly return something like:

```
 € 1,234.57
```

This has just happened to Latvia. This year, it converted to the euro. Various systems contain both amounts in letvian lats and euros. I need to be able to still print and format old currencies. And I need to be sure new currencies can also be handled. This formatting is not just about the symbol, but also about the placement (before, after, with or without space) and the local number format (decimal separator and thousands separator).

Every amount in our database has a currency (e.g. EUR) and a corresponding culture (e.g. nl-NL). Euro amounts are formatting differently depending on if they originate from our German or our Dutch office. (they both use euros, but format the amounts differently)

- Does dotnet provide access to older currencies?
- What is a future-proof way of writing the formatting amounts?

Right now, the only way I can think of, is to copy the culture-database to my database.

Comment: AFAIK .NET does not provide legacy cultures that you can use, but it seems straightforward enough: your app needs to provide `CultureInfo` objects that represent both the old and new regimes and select among them appropriately. Depending on .NET to do the right thing is not an option when you work with monetary transactions.

Comment: @Jon: I thought so. I need to store (a copy of) the CultureInfo for every used currency in my database, so I can keep using it if the world changes.

Comment: Yes. It also works the other way: e.g. Latvia switches to the euro tomorrow at 00:00 local time, but .NET won't magically get updated on the users' machines at that same moment. You would need to update your app in preparation.

Comment: That [was done](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805202/in-latvia-currenty-is-latvian-lats-not-euro).  Keep your .NET Framework version updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (by [cloning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one and modifying) which uses a different currency symbol/format (ie. set its [`NumberFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a different instance of [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Then pass this `CultureInfo` to formatting functions as needed.

As the comment to the question notes, .NET (and Windows in general) doesn't provide historic data (similarly for time zones but there's a [library for that](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)). In the cases you need you'll need to hold enough data yourself.

Remember [ISO-4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency codes are not reused under such a change, so holding that against amounts allows you to format correctly. Additionally just because a country formats their currency amounts one way doesn't mean everyone does. Eg. 25 French Francs was be "FF25.00" in the UK but "25FF00" or "FF25,00" in other locales. (EDIT: I note you covered this last paragraph in the question.)

Comment: This (Replacing NumberFormatInfo) is the solition I chose. +1 for the library; maybe I'll also create a library for historic currency data.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the simplest way is to not use the locale-specific currency format, but rather to format the amount as a simple *number* and pre- or suffix it with the ISO currency code. The convention

```
       ------------
Sum:   ATS 1.376,00  (= EUR 100,00)
```

is commonly found on invoices (using locale `de-AT` as an example).

If you want to use the built-in currency formatting options, I would suggest to replace the currency symbol with the one stored in the database. I.e., in your `currency` table, you'd need to map currencies to symbols:

```
EUR -> €
ATS -> S
...
```

and then you'd replace [`myCultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the one in the database. That way, you ensure that a value is never shown with the wrong currency symbol.

Comment: I would also require to store the currency sign position (before/after, with/without space) and the number of decimals. So I opted for storing the complete NumberFormatInf data in my currency table.

Comment: @realbart I assume your currencies table stores by both currency and locale (latter being the locale of the user): amounts in EUR (for example) are not formatted the same in fr-fr and en-us (eg. decimal separator reflects client not currency). This would be clearest where a country has a specific sign (eg. as India now does), but it is not widely used (or recognised) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows 8 or above, this deficiency is addressed by the [Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.numberformatting.currencyformatter.aspx). It requires that you provide the explicit currency and you can also explicitly provide a language.