# Currency symbol from ¥ to 円

Tags: c#, currency, cultureinfo

There is a requirement to change the currency symbol for yen ¥ to  円
But Using Culture info if I use ja-JP as language code its resolves to ¥ only.

I have seen in some sites (Japanese) the hepburn symbol has been implemented.
Any idea how achieve the same.
¥500   to 500円

Position can changed through NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern  but not sure about the symbol.

CultureInfo cs = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
 cs.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 1;

Comment: What control are you trying to have this show in?

Comment: You can create a custom formatter

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316517/custom-currency-symbol-and-decimal-places-using-decimal-tostringc-and-cultur?

Comment: Does `NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` not do what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Currency symbol and decimal places using decimal.ToString("C") and CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316517/custom-currency-symbol-and-decimal-places-using-decimal-tostringc-and-cultur)

Comment: NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol i was setting to 円. Thought of testing in separate console app, and was rendering as question mark (?). Looks to me as limitation of console only, doesn't support this character

Answer (score 0):

This is a related question: [How to use cultureinfo to format depricated currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996563/how-to-use-cultureinfo-to-format-deprecated-currencies)

The answer is the same:

You can create a custom `CultureInfo` (by cloning one and modifying) which uses a different currency symbol/format (ie. set its `NumberFormat` to a different instance of `NumberFormatInfo`).

Then pass this `CultureInfo` to formatting functions as needed.

As the comment to the question notes, .NET (and Windows in general) doesn't provide historic data (similarly for time zones but there's a library for that). In the cases you need you'll need to hold enough data yourself.
Remember ISO-4217 currency codes are not reused under such a change, so holding that against amounts allows you to format correctly. Additionally just because a country formats their currency amounts one way doesn't mean everyone does. Eg. 25 French Francs was be "FF25.00" in the UK but "25FF00" or "FF25,00" in other locales. (EDIT: I note you covered this last paragraph in the question.)

Comment: Appreciate your help. So the solution looks to me is to set the CurrencySymbol of NumberFormat after cloning. I was not able to see the symbol 円 in console, instead was getting ?(Question mark). Probably because Console doesn't support this character